# Java Record Data Type Doesn't Work For Network Communication

Tags: java, java-14, java-record

I thought the new Java Record data type in Java 14 should be suitable for data crossing the network because the data shouldn't change in the process which is the main feature of the record data type - immutable.

I use the data type in RSocket. On the sender side, I get an error on encoder. I haven't found what the encoder is about. On the receiver side, I get a deserializer error. To my knowledge, a record can't implement an interface such as the Serializable.

So, the record data type doesn't work for network programming, is that right?

**Update:**

I add the Serializable interface to the record definition on the both sender and receiver sides. After sending out a request, it is fine on the TCP sender side, but an error on the receiver side

```
No encoder for com.....data.Notification, current value type is class com.....data.Notification
```

Have those who marked this question have a different experience?

Comment: You might wanna read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/records-serialization.html#serialization-of-records)

Comment: If it might be of interest to resolve, what error do you get when you say *I get a deserializer error*?

Comment: @Naman After I got the deserializer error, I changed my code back to class type. My PC crashed afterward. Once I can reproduce the error, I will post the error message here.

Answer (score 5):

> To my knowledge, a record can't implement an interface such as the
>   Serializable.

It can. Just add `implements Serializable` to its declaration. It cannot extend any other class because it already extends `Record`, if that's what you mean.

See [JEP-359](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359)

> Beyond the restrictions above, records behave like normal classes:
>   they can be declared top level or nested, they can be generic, **they
>   can implement interfaces**, and they are instantiated via the new
>   keyword.

Comment: To my test, Implementing Serializable alone doesn't make a record work for data crossing the network.

Comment: I don't know anything about RSocket, to be honest, I just corrected your point about records. You could try without records. Records are not supposed to be used in production yet,